Can I use parquet format v2 when writing delta tables from spark?
is there a way to configure spark to write a specific version of parquet format when writing a dataframe as a delta table?
I could not find anything to help me configure the file format version in spark.
Currently spark write version 1.0 of parquet when creating delta table.
Background- delta writes parquet 1.0 version files which do not support nanoseconds precision timestamps. In short, I currently face data loss when creating delta table from my source files.
The newer parquet format version- >2.0 supports that.
github link
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1387
So I want to have delta table that have 2.0 version parquet files.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

are you using OSS or Databricks Runtime?

databricks runtime @Kashyap

I guess my answer answers your question then.

amended answer based on updated question: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/643 is tracking nano usage
Delta is not parquet, please see the oss delta docs for details: https://docs.delta.io/latest/
You should use the correctly versioned Delta libraries to access Delta files.
Without using the transaction log you cannot correctly interpret the state of any file, parquet or otherwise, underneath the root directory (see the protocol for more details).  Change feeds, deletion vectors, indexes etc. all require using the log.  The writer and reader protocols are carefully planned for predictable compatibility, changing the actual parquet version used could break all delta usage by the supporting libraries.

Delta writes parquet files in the back end. There are no delta format files.

per the edit, that's largely irrelevant - the additional book keeping outside of parquet is what makes it Delta.  If you are looking for something more specific you should provide the reason for wanting to modify the parquet version used (and therefore the libraries) so people can better understand and help.

Thank you for the input. Updated the question. Let me know if anything can be provided by me

That's a lot a jargon thrown around without understanding the question, let alone answering it. And PS: in this context "Delta is parquet".

--- updated ---
It seems you can, though not sure if it helps you.
Use spark.hadoop.parquet.writer.version=v2 with delta lake 2.4.0+ release, to make parquet writer use v2.
E.g.
$ pyspark  --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0 \
           --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
           --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" \
           --conf "spark.hadoop.parquet.writer.version=v2"
--- snip ---
>>> spark.range(0, 5).write.format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table-v2")
>>>

Then verify that the
>>> import pyarrow.parquet as pq
>>> pm2 = pq.read_metadata('/tmp/delta-table-v2/part-00000-4e89266c-2ea1-4fa0-ae4b-77612d538aea-c000.snappy.parquet')
>>> pm2.row_group(0).column(0)
--- snip ---
  encodings: ('DELTA_BINARY_PACKED',)
--- snip ---
>>>

DELTA_BINARY_PACKED is a v2 encoding.
Without spark.hadoop.parquet.writer.version=v2, you'll see encodings: ('BIT_PACKED', 'RLE', 'PLAIN') in column metadata. Which are the parquet v1 encodings.

Reason why this may not help is, I think, you're trying to create a delta table from a pyspark.sql.Dataframe, which uses Spark data types, which doesn't support nanosecond precision. I.e. you can write pure python code using pyarrow etc to create a parquet file that has a "time" column with nanosecond precision. But that's not a delta table.
I'm no expert on pandas, but see if it's possible to do this through pandas Dataframe API.

Only possible workaround I can think of is to store this column as LongType and then write udfs for every datetime operation you want to perform on this column (instead of using built-in spark.sql.functions).
Inside the udfs you can convert the long to datetime, perform the operation (and return a long again if needed). Stock python datetime.datetime doesn't support nanosecond precision. So you'll have to either create your own wrapper (datetime_with_ns) or deal with timestamp as a long.
If you can implement the udfs as pandas-udfs, then you'll get a huge performance boost too.
Tedious but better than storing as a string. You'll get almost the full benefit of Spark distributed computing.
